# Is there a way to place importance in which route to be displayed first?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
<div className="app">
      <Router>
        {/* If there is no user, render the login screen else render the app components */}
        {!user ? (
          <LoginScreen/>
        ) : (!plan ? (
          <ProfileScreen/>
        ) : (
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path = '/'>
              <Watching/>
            </Route>
            
            <Route exact path ="/home">
              <HomeScreen/>
            </Route>

            <Route exact path='/profile'>
              <ProfileScreen/>
            </Route>

            <Route exact path='/ManageProfiles'>
              <ManageProfiles/>
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        ))
        }
      </Router>
        
</div>
```

In my `App.js`, these are the my routes components. Upon logging in, the route component with path `/profile` will be displayed immediately instead of `/home`. Is there a way to ensure that everytime i log in, it would redirect me to `/home`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use useNavigate hook and redirect your user by using it in your Login handler like that:

```
//Inside your component
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    yourLoginHandler() {
      ...othercode
      navigate("/home")
}
```

Comment: Ohh okiee i will look into useNavigate hook hahaha first time seeing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just after you login, you navigate the route to /home. You can use history for that.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

const history = useHistory();

login().then(() => history.push('/home'));
```

Comment: Thank you!! But is there a way to specify it inside the <switch>  or <route> component